# List as value of session variable in Django

Tags: python, django, list, session, unicode

I'm building a small Django app.  The user is to build up a list of pairs of strings, by repeatedly submitting a pair of forms.  The list is stored as value of a session variable.

But there is a problem. When the list is loaded by the view, the strings which were to be elements of the pairs in the list wind up getting prefixed by the letter u.  So for example as elements of the list instead of

```
['a','b']
['c','d']
```

we get

```
[u'a',u'b']
[u'c',u'd']
```

My impression is that Django treats values of session variables as strings.  So maybe the problem has something to do with the conversion of lists?

Here is the source of the view:

```
def plisting(request):
    if 'plist' not in request.session:
        request.session['plist']=[]
    plist = request.session['plist']
    if 'entry' in request.POST:
        entry = str(request.POST['entry'])
        key = str(request.POST['key'])
        plist = plist+[[entry,key]]
    request.session['plist'] = plist
    return render(request,'evaluator/plisting.html',{'plist':plist})
```

Answer (score 1):

The `u` at the beginning of the string returned to your view function just means that the strings are encoded in [unicode](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings). You need not handle it specially in your code. Accessing the list just normally will return you the expected strings.

This is what I mean:

```
>>> a = [u'a',u'b']
>>> b = [u'c',u'd']
>>> a[1]
'b'
>>> b[0]
'c'
```

As evident from the output, when you access the elements, you do not see the 'u' as part of the strings.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The output will be `u'b'` and `u'c'` respectively.

Comment: @Sid Have you tried that with a python 2.7+ interpreter?

Comment: @DanielRoseman and @Sid Agreed that the unicode string is still preserved. But in the context of OP's question they do not have to care about processing the elements of the array and stripping the `u` character.

Comment: So just to clarify: when the list is recovered from a session variable, and another tuple, whose elements are drawn from session.POST, is appended to it, then in the resulting extended list, the elements of all but the last tuple will be unicode?  (That's how it looks from the resulting HTML.)  But nonetheless according to @DanielRoseman, this will not compromise testing whether an element of one tuple is the same as an element of another tuple?  Thanks again...  (Sorry for the n00b question.)

Comment: To answer that last question: yes, somehow the testing isn't affected.  (Bug was elsewhere...)

Comment: Of course, yes, it doesn't matter, but @shaktimaan had already answered that. I just wanted to point out that it would still be `unicode`. @shaktiman, yes, I use 2.7.6

Comment: Hmmm.  I still have a function, whose intended arguments are tuples, which returns different values according to whether the elements of tuples are represented in unicode.  For example `inst([u'@',u'F',u'x'], u'x',[u'@',u'F',u'a'])` returns `False` but  `inst(['@', 'F', 'x'],'x',['@', 'F', 'a'])` returns `True`.